# PHP eval $a="$a"?

Tags: php, eval

I was looking through some code for work, and came across this line:

```
eval("\$element = \"$element\";");
```

I'm really confused as to why any PHP developer would've written this line.  What purpose does this serve, besides setting a variable to itself?

Luckily, the function this line is in is never called.

Comment: Rasmus Lerdorf, the creator of PHP, once wrote that "if eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question"

Comment: So it seems that this line just expands variables that were inside a single quoted string.  As with all uses of `eval`, there is a better way.  I'm not sure why the person who wrote this just didn't use double quotes...

Comment: This show really well, that `eval` is not only highly dangerous (if the user could in some way contribute to the value of `$element` you were totally screwed), but also absolutely unmaintainable. I had to think several minutes before I really understood what this is supposed to do. You get a +1 for this great example.

Comment: I found another instance of this in our code.  This time it was used because the developer didn't know how to use variable variables (or well, that's what I used to replace the `eval` with).

Comment: [`gettype()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) now returns `string` - `$element` is casted into a string.

Comment: @Shi: That's not what this does.  If you read the answer, you'll see it's a crappy templating engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
echo $str. "\n";
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
This is a $string with my $name in it.
This is a cup with my coffee in it.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

I do just ctl+c ctrl+v :-)

Comment: Why would someone use `eval` do do that?  Just use double quotes to have PHP expand the variables for you (or use `str_replace` to replace `$string` and `$name`).

Comment: @Rocket: I think you are right about that. It is bad practice. The answer is very informative in my opinion though.

Comment: Yea, you wouldn't do this because it's stupid. However, zod has quite correctly demonstrated one possible reason why the author of the code thought that he should.

Comment: +1 not because one should use this code, but for figuring out the puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

It converts the value of the variable to a string, but I wouldn't recommend using it.

Use the function `strval()` instead. Have a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php).

Comment: Doesn't PHP automatically convert variables to strings where necessary?

Comment: @Rocket: I think in most cases, yes. I am not sure about all cases. There must be a reason for the function `strval()` to exist. If you need to be sure that the value you are using is a string, I would explicitly say so by using something like `strval()`.

Answer (score 1):

This assigns the string-converted contents of the variable `$element` to a variable called `$element`. Another way to do this is to use `strval`, or in some cases `print_r($x, true)`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really do much except converting the value to string or might serve as a poor alternative to `sprintf`. But if the variable contains double quotes, this is gonna cause some trouble. You really wouldn't want to eval a code like this:

```
$element = 'foo"bar';
```

Not to mention some even more harmful code. Seems like a place for a "php injection" :D

Don't use it.