# Executing a function by variable name in Python

Tags: python

What I need to do is loop over a large number of different files and (try to) fetch metadata from the files.

I can make a large if...elif... and test for every extension, but I think it would be much easier to store the extension in a variable, check if a function with that name exists, and execute it.

This is my current solution, taken from another stackoverflow thread:

```
try:
    getattr(modulename, funcname)(arg)
except AttributeError:
    print 'function not found "%s" (%s)' % (funcname, arg)
```

There is a problem with this:
If the underlying function raises an AttributeError, this is registered as a "function not found" error.
I can add try...except blocks to all functions, but that would not be particularly pretty either ...

What I'm looking for is more something like:

```
if function_exists(fun):
  execute_function(fun, arg)
```

Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do :

```
func = getattr(modulename, funcname, None):
if func:
    func(arg)
```

Or maybe better:

```
try:
    func = getattr(modulename, funcname)
except AttributeError:
    print 'function not found "%s" (%s)' % (funcname, arg)
else:
    func(arg)
```

Comment: I'd wrap `func(arg)` in a `try:` and catch TypeError in case the module has an attribute `func` that isn't callable.

Comment: @Wooble : good suggestion or he can also do : `if func and callable(func):`

Answer (score 4):

The way I found is:

Code

```
def My_Function():
     print ("Hello World!")

FunctionName = "My_Function"

(FunctionName)()
```

Output

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: Should be eval(FunctionName)()

Answer (score 3):

The [`gettattr` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) has an optional third argument for a default value to return if the attribute does not exist, so you could use that:

```
fun = getattr(modulename, funcname, None)

if fun is None:
    print 'function not found "%s" (%s)' % (funcname, arg)
else
    fun(arg)
```

Answer (score -1):

Like @mouad said, `callable(function)` can call a function.

You can use this to call a function from inside a variable using this:

```
callable(SAVE())
```

This will call the function that is specified as the arg.

To use this inside a variable:

```
Save = callable(SAVE())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try

```
eval('func_name()')
```

Comment: Though this answer is about Python (about which, I admin, know nothing), not about PHP, but even so, I still believe that [this statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340442/php-eval-a-a#comment6029671_5340442) is true even for Python: "_Rasmus Lerdorf, the creator of PHP, once wrote that »if eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question«_"!