# How do you call a Function from a Variable? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, save, python-3.2

**Before you claim as a duplicate**
I have looked at the following: 
 [python function call with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431216/python-function-call-with-variable)

[Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name)

[Executing a function by variable name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391199/executing-a-function-by-variable-name-in-pythonhttps://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1110989)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1110989

and much more, but no luck.

---

I am developing a game. Right now I am working on the ***SAVE/LOAD*** feature, but I am getting nowhere.

I want to take a piece of text from another **py** or **txt** file and have my main **py** file read that, and call a function depending on the string of text in the second file.

---

Script1:

```
#imports

from script2 import SaveCode

#Code

def Test():
    print('Hello, World!')

callable(SaveCode)
```

---

Script2:

```
SaveCode = Test()
```

This won't work. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please add traceback.

Comment: @scharette there is no traceback. It won't display anything. It doesn't call anything, it just exits, like to program is done.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @cdarke It is supposed to call the `Test()` function, but it doesn't do it

Comment: Where is `callable` defined?

Comment: `callable` is just a test if something could be called. It's a built-in.

Comment: What should I use to call the Test() from another file?

Comment: [Callable()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#callable) returns True or False. It does not execute the function.

Comment: There _is_ a way to tell Python to execute the `Test()` function via the string `'Test()'`, but it's really _not_ a good idea to organize your code that way when there are cleaner, safer alternatives.

Comment: `retn = eval(SaveCode)` will work, but (see other comments) it is dangerous.  Why do you need two modules for this?

Comment: Because I don't know how to edit the contents of a python file using the same file

Comment: You don't need to edit it, you can choose different functions by assigning a function to a variable, for example:  `runit = Func1`  or `runit = Func2` then just call `runit()`.  The dictionary method in @Bahrom's answer is a good way of doing it (called a *dispatch table*).

Comment: Why do you want your script to edit a Python file? I thought you were just trying to add a simple SAVE / LOAD feature to your game. So you should be writing and reading data to a game save file. You shouldn't be modifying the Python code of some file!

Comment: yes, but when you exit a python file, they get set back to their defaults. IE. var1 = string, and in the program it changes it to string1. When you exit the program it changes back to string

Comment: @PM2Ring how would i do this?

Comment: You create a data file that has the data you want in it. When the program starts it reads the data so it can set your key variables to their initial values. And when you want to save the game you write the current values of those key variables to the file. If the data is simple you can just use a simple text file to do that. But if things are complicated you can use some kind of structured data file, like JSON. Another option is to use the `pickle` module which can save various Python objects and load them back in.

Comment: @PM2Ring oh. ok.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work unless you use evaluate that string using `eval` or `exec` which [isn't recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided).

From what I gather you have a string in script2 and want to execute a function in script1 based on that string. What you could do is define a dictionary that contains the strings you have mapped to the functions you want called:

In **script1**:

```
#imports

from script2 import SaveCode

#Code

def Test():
    print('Hello, World!')

functions = {
    'Test': Test
}

# Assuming that SaveCode = 'Test' in your second script,
# look up the corresponding function
function_to_run = functions[SaveCode]
# and call it
function_to_run() # prints Hello, World!
```

In **script2**:

```
SaveCode = 'Test'
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\csc1AB\PROJECTS_\TEST\script1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from script2 import SaveCode
  File "C:\csc1AB\PROJECTS_\TEST\script2.py", line 1, in <module>
    functions[SaveCode]()
NameError: name 'functions' is not defined

Comment: You're missing the `functions = {...` line in the first script

Comment: i copied everything from your answer into the 2 scripts

Comment: Read the comments in the answer

Comment: @ChaseBarnes:  I don't see anything in that answer which says you should replace both scripts.  Anyway, that is not the intention.

Comment: "# Assuming that SaveCode = 'Test' in your second script, look up the corresponding function
# and call it"

Comment: I'll update my answer to make it clearer if there are still questions when I get back to my desk.

Comment: @ChaseBarnes the comment in the code just meant that I was assuming you had a variable in your script2 called `SaveCode` and that its value was `'Test'`. Anyway, I updated the code to show the contents of both script1 and script2.

Comment: @ChaseBarnes and..? Do you still get that exception? See my edited answer for contents of script1 and script2.