# Eval Purpose | SQL transormation?

Tags: php, mysql

I store my sql queries as strings and then use them later in PDO as shown below.

There is one line that I don't understand:

```
eval("\$query = \"$query\";");
```

From the docs..eval should run a string as PHP code.  Why can't I just use `$query` directly?  What does it mean to run a string of SQL?

This code works.  I just don't know what `eval()` statement is for.

Note this is safe `eval()` as the input is not user defined.

```
    "arc_id" =>                 "SELECT id FROM credentials WHERE email=?",
    "arc_id_from_hash" =>       "SELECT id FROM credentials WHERE pass=?",
    "signin_pass" =>            "SELECT pass FROM credentials WHERE email=?",
    "signin_validate" =>        "SELECT id, hash FROM credentials WHERE email=? AND pass=?"
);
public function __construct()  
{
    $this->db_one = parent::get();
}
public function _pdoQuery($fetchType, $queryType, $parameterArray=0) // needs review
{
    $query=$this->sql_array[$queryType];

    // what?

    eval("\$query = \"$query\";");

    // if not input parameters, no need to prep

    if($parameterArray==0)
    {
        $pdoStatement = $this->db_one->query($query);
```

Comment: Your question reads like you want us to explain your code to you, which you don't understand, and to tell you why you can't do something which you actually can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eval("\$query = \"$query\";");
```

This is a variable replacer/templating engine.

It is replacing variables inside `$query` with their values.

I suggest not using `eval` for this, it'd probably be better to use `preg_replace` or `str_replace`.

For reference, here's a question I asked: [PHP eval $a="$a"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340442/php-eval-a-a)

Answer (score 3):

That code looks up the query by name, e.g. `arch_id` -> `'SELECT id ..'`, and then evaluates the query under a double-quote context in `eval`.

Presumable the queries *could* contain variables which would be interpolated. For instance, the original value might be `'SELECT id WHERE food = "$taste"'` which would then then be evaluated as a double-quoted string literal in the `eval` and result in the interpolation of `$taste` so the result stored back in `$query` might then be `'SELECT id WHERE food = "yucky"'`.

Given the data it appears to be "too clever" junk left over from a previous developer. Get rid of it. (If something similar is required in the future, although I would recommend strictly using placeholders, consider non-`eval` alternative mechanisms.)

Comment: @HiroProtagonist "Bad" is subjective. It surely is *more dangerous* when user-input is eval'ed :) Generally I find there are much *cleaner* (and less confusing) ways to solve problems than with `eval`.